# Calculate max of all cells of a raster with gdal_calc.py

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-calc

I want to calculate max of all cells of a raster, i.e. the result should be a scalar.

Regardless of what I call `amax`, `max`, `numpy.max(A, axis=0)` I always get a raster with the same WxH as the original raster. I suppose I should get a single scalar value. Is this possible with `gdal_calc.py`?

```
gdal_calc.py -A 0009.TIF --calc "max(A)" --debug
gdal_calc.py -A 0009.TIF --calc "numpy.max(A, axis=0)" --debug

gdal_calc.py starting calculation numpy.max(A, axis=0)
file A: 0009.TIF, dimensions: 7800, 7900, type: UInt16
Generating output file gdal_calc.tif
output file: gdal_calc.tif, dimensions: 7800, 7900, type: UInt16
using blocksize 7800 x 1
0 .. 10 .. 20 .. 30 .. 40 .. 50 .. 60 .. 70 .. 80 .. 90 .. 100 - Done

gdalinfo gdal_calc.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: gdal_calc.tif
Size is 7800, 7900
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",15],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32633"]]
Origin = (271485.000000000000000,4743015.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (30.000000000000000,-30.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  271485.000, 4743015.000) ( 12d12'19.09"E, 42d48'20.13"N)
Lower Left  (  271485.000, 4506015.000) ( 12d17'46.77"E, 40d40'24.15"N)
Upper Right (  505485.000, 4743015.000) ( 15d 4' 1.63"E, 42d50'22.88"N)
Lower Right (  505485.000, 4506015.000) ( 15d 3'53.75"E, 40d42'18.09"N)
Center      (  388485.000, 4624515.000) ( 13d39'30.36"E, 41d45'52.71"N)
Band 1 Block=7800x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=65535
```

Comment: Thanks. Why `gdal_calc` does not report that this is not possible? This is a kind of a mismatch with `numpy` semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible with `gdal_calc`, use `gdalinfo -stats` instead and read the max value from the output.

The `gdal_calc` documentation states "*all files must have the same dimensions*", this includes the output file.

Comment: ` "all files must have the same dimensions" this includes the output file.` -- this should be explicitly stated in the docs